# Typescript error: 'List<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using typescript along with react in my project and I have created a simple component where I would like to map through a list and create react elements:

```
const FlightSchedule: React.FC<{ flightRoute: List<Entity<FlightLeg>> }> = ({flightRoute}) => flightRoute.map(route =>
    <DescriptionList key={route.get('flightId')}>
      <TermDescriptionGroup description={route.get('flightId')}/>
      <TermDescriptionGroup description={route.get('flightDate')} topMargin/>
    </DescriptionList>)
```

But, I get a following typescript error:

```
Type 'List<Element>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key
```

Why do I get this error, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you need to show us what `List`, `Entity`, and `FlightLeg` are.

Comment: Also dump React.FC: https://www.harrymt.com/blog/2020/05/20/react-typescript-react-fc.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately because the signature of a `React.FC` is that it [returns a single `ReactElement`](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components/), your (elegant) `map` over the incoming list won't work - you're effectively returning a list of `ReactElement`s.

You'll need to wrap the whole thing, as here in a `Fragment`, and then do the mapping inside that:

```
const FlightSchedule: React.FC<{ flightRoute: List<Entity<FlightLeg>> }> = ({ flightRoute }) => (
  <>
    {flightRoute.map((route) => (
      <DescriptionList key={route.get('flightId')}>
        <TermDescriptionGroup description={route.get('flightId')} />
        <TermDescriptionGroup description={route.get('flightDate')} topMargin />
      </DescriptionList>
    ))}
  </>
)
```